# Simultaneous execution of several Asynctask not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

**CURRENT SCENARIO**

I have a requirement that I have to run an `asynctask` on click of a button and send some data to the server and don't show any progress to the user. Now if user press the button again a new instance of asynctask will execute without waiting for the previous version to finish. This I am able to achieve using this class.

```
    public class AsyncTaskTools {
    public static <P, T extends AsyncTask<P, ?, ?>> void execute(T task) {
        execute(task, (P[]) null);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static <P, T extends AsyncTask<P, ?, ?>> void execute(T task, P... params) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
        } else {
            task.execute(params);
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

Now when I run the same code in Android Kitkat it doesn't gives success response after first asynctask and that too only if I click button with short interval between them. If I wait for say 5-10 seconds before clicking the button again then my code works perfectly fine, but when I click button rapidly about 5 times, my code fails to work.

**Only issue that I was able to catch related to this is the following**

```
    exceeded content-length limit of 12900 bytes
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
```

This exception is caught some time in catch block.

This is my complete asynctask code.

```
class SendCallDispositionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        public SendCallDispositionAsyncTask() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            //this.activity = profile_Info;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
//                utils.showProgressDialog(ActivityCallScreen.this, "Loading. Please wait..");
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String responseArray = null;
            Log.d("asyncresponse", "do in background");
            CallDurationReceiver.start_time=0;
            try {
                byte[] data;

                try {
                    Log.d("callduration","Duration:  "+prefManager.getDouble(PrefrenceConstants.CALL_DURATION));
                    MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                    entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                    entity.addPart("userid", new StringBody(String.valueOf(prefManager.getInt(PrefrenceConstants.USER_ID))));
                    entity.addPart("dialerno", new StringBody(mobile));
                    entity.addPart("dipositionid", new StringBody(dispositionId));
                    entity.addPart("dipositiongroup", new StringBody(dipositiongroup));
                    entity.addPart("callduration", new StringBody(prefManager.getDouble(PrefrenceConstants.CALL_DURATION)+""));
                    entity.addPart("callename", new StringBody(name));
                    entity.addPart("calleage", new StringBody(age));
                    entity.addPart("callecontact", new StringBody(contact));
                    entity.addPart("isnote", new StringBody(checked));
                    entity.addPart("cbdate", new StringBody(date));
                    entity.addPart("aliment", new StringBody(aliment));
                    entity.addPart("callelocation", new StringBody(location));
                    entity.addPart("remarks", new StringBody(selectedRemarks));
                    entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
                    entity.addPart("contactid", new StringBody(String.valueOf(contact_id)));

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = entity.build();
                    URL url = new URL(sendDispositionUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
                    httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", prefManager.getString(PrefrenceConstants.API_KEY));

                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
//                        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-length", httpEntity.getContentLength() + "");
                    httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty(httpEntity.getContentType().getName(), httpEntity.getContentType().getValue());

                    OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    httpEntity.writeTo(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                    os.close();
                    httpURLConnection.connect();
                    if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        response = BufferReaderMaker.readContentFromIS(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                        Log.v("log_tag", "image upload status ::: " + response);
                    } else if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
                        response = BufferReaderMaker.readContentFromIS(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                        Log.d("responce", response);


                    }
//                        {"error":true,"message":"Required field(s) userid, dialerno, dipositionid, dipositiongroup, callduration, contactid is missing or empty"}

                } catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.d("host", e.getMessage());

                }
            } catch (final ConnectTimeoutException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.d("timeout", e.getMessage());


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("exec", e.getMessage());

            }
            return null;

//            return "Success";

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.d("asyncresponse", response);
//                utils.hideProgressDialog();

        }
    }
```

I checked several links regarding this issue but none of them is working for me.

Can anybody tell me if this is some problem in my code or a server side issue.

**EDIT**

Also I am uploading a file to the server which is about 50 kb currently.Can this cause any issue?

Answer (score 1):

It sound like your problem might be the length of content you are posting.

```
httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-length", httpEntity.getContentLength() + "");
```

You need to get the length in bytes. You should check to see what value `httpEntity.getContentLength()`   returns. It should be the number of bytes you are uploading - including the size of the file.

You might have some restrictions on the amount of data you may upload - but I doubt that is the problem, because that is not many bytes in the error message.

I use this code with no issues:

```
public String makeHttpRequestJsonString(String path, int requestType, Map<String, String> params){
    String json = "";
    InputStream responseStream = null;

    try {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()){
            if(postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }

        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        URL url = makeURL(path, requestType);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));

        DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        request.write(postDataBytes);
        request.flush();
        //Some people have reported issues when closing the the request before reading the 
        request.close();

        //Check the response code of the server -
        Integer replyCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        //System.out.println("Reply Code:  " + replyCode.toString());

        responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));

        String line = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        responseStreamReader.close();

        json = stringBuilder.toString();

    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "makeHttpRequestJsonString --- " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return json;
}
```

I add my data differently but you could adapt your solution.

Comment: mine is multpart request not simple json request

Comment: My point was it seems like the problem is coming from  your `httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-length", httpEntity.getContentLength() + "");` I didn't see that you were adding a file. I just saw that you were uploading what looked to be quite a few parameters. You should check to see if the content length is the same size as the error message you are getting. if not - that is your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help I have now switched to retrofit and it seems to be working properly

Comment: From your error message and the file size you mentioned it seems that the   `httpEntity.getContentLength()` is not capturing the size of the file, but when the server reads your content it deems it too large and is rejecting it.

Comment: After changing to retrofit it still gives this issue sometimes. Can you tell me whether this is an app side or server side issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with retrofit. But from the error message it appears to be a app side issue. If retrofit requires you to manually input the content length similar to the original code then **you should check the length of bytes by dumping the value to the console** and check to see what the value is. It should be at least as large as the file you are attempting to upload